# Need help understanding this TSQL join behavior

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, outer-join

I just do not know how to google for my question, so I apologize if there is an answer out there for this question already. I have my query working, but while I was troubleshooting, I came across behavior I don't understand.

I have three tables with the exact same structure--one for employees that have been terminated, one for employees that have chosen to waive medical coverage, and one for employees that do not have medical coverage. There are multiple companies in this data, and I am grouping by company and division.

I am doing FULL OUTER JOINs because some company/division groups may have 0 terminated employees, but may have some waiver employees(for example).

The structure of the three source tables are:
Company---Division---NumbOfEmployees

The structure of the destination view is:

Company---Division---NumbOfTermEmp---NumbOfWaiverEmp---NumbOfNonMedEmp

So I am basically flattening out the data.

If I join table 1 to table 2 and then table 2 to table 3, I get the data I expect.

If I join table 1 to table 2, and then table 1 to table 3, I do not. I will get an extra row where, for instance, no data exists in table 1 but it does in table 2.

Visual representation below:

[image]

I do not understand what is going on behind the scenes enough to figure out this behavior. Why is this?

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: @JClark Can you post your SQL code? its difficult to see the problem without the code.

Comment: I'll work on modifying the data for privacy and posting. @GordonLinoff, I have a working SQL statement with desired results, I just don't understand a certain JOIN mechanic I ran into while getting my working SQL statement

Comment: Belay that. Tab's answer helped me understand what is going on. No need for more code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can immediately think of at least one scenario that would cause this.

Doing your "Bad" join (both T2 and T3 join to T1), suppose you have a row that exists in T2 and T3, but not T1.

Then you are basically doing this:

```
First Join
T1    T2    
NULL  Data

Second Join
T1    T3
NULL  Data
```

And since nowhere are you joining T2 to T3, it doesn't see the connection of "Data" in both columns, so it creates two rows.  One for the first join and one for the second.

To really flatten the data, you should include a relationship between T2 & T3 in your join condition to T3 (T3 joins to both T1 & T2).

At least, I **think** that would work, with both joins being FULL OUTER.

Comment: I am marking this as the answer because it specifically answers the question and helped me understand what is going on. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you again Tab for the understanding. The key for me ended up being group by with the ISNULL function. The ISNULL helping to group the rows accordingly when one table had a null value for the division/company (data input errors).
GROUP BY ISNULL( ISNULL(N.Company, ISNULL(T.Company, W.Company)), ISNULL(N.Division, ISNULL(T.Division, W.Division))

Comment: I forgot to mention it was also necessary to have a MAX() around the sum because the number columns were not in the GROUP BY:
,max(ISNULL(N.NumbOfNonMedEmp,0))          AS 'NumbOfNonMedEmp'

Without the max, an error would be thrown saying that the column was not in the group by clause. MAX is ok here because the number would be the same between rows.

Answer (score 2):

If, by flatten the data, you mean one row per employee with the information from the other tables, then `full outer join` is one possibility.  Another is `union all` with aggregation:

```
select NumbOfEmployees,
       sum(NumTerminated) as NumTerminated,
       sum(NumWaiver) as NumWaiver,
       sum(NumNonMed) as NumNonMed
from ((select Company, Division,
              NumbOfEmployees as NumTerminated, 0 as NumWaiver, 0 as NumNonMed
       from terminations
      ) union all
      (select Company, Division,
              0 as NumTerminated, NumbOfEmployees as NumWaiver, 0 as NumNonMed
       from waivers
      ) union all
      (select Company, Division,
              0 as NumTerminated, 0 as NumWaiver, NumbOfEmployees as NumNonMed
       from waivers
      )
     ) cd
group by Company, Division;
```

`Full outer join`s can be difficult to work with, particularly with multiple tables, because the join keys may not have matched an earlier join.  My preference would be to have a list of all companies and divisions, and then use `left join` instead.  Or, the above query using `union all` and `group by`.

Comment: Interesting. I have never thought of UNION with aggregation before. This seems even more straightforward. I will try it out.